# Get scroll position of draggable LineChart

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

Probably a very simple question: I have created a simple draggable/scrollable linechart and need to get the current scroll position to determine whether I have reached the end of the chart. So something like -100 points in the example below.

[image: LineChart with scroll offset]

EDIT: 
It doesn't necessarily need to be the scroll position but more importantly an indicator telling that I have reached the newest (most right) value in the line chart.

Comment: did you found any?